# Función que lee los datos del estado en react, pero no me los muestra completos

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, asincronismo

Tengo un codigo que lo que hace es pedir a firestore (firebase) informacion para poder mostrarla, pero en firestore no existe lo que en otras bases de datos llamaríamos "llaves foráneas", en realidad si hay algo parecido pero no permiten obtener los datos de forma sencilla como en mySql o sqlServer. Asi que al pedir la infomacion de un elemento que tenga una "llave foranea" debemos pedir por separa la infomacion de esa "llave foranea".

```
const Rutas = () => {

  const [rutasList, setRutasList] = useState([]);
  var listeninDb;
  var listeninDb2;

//La funcion getinfo() manda a pedir los datos, en la funcion se hacen dos peticiones primero la del 
//elemento principal y despues pide la informacion que de la "llave foranea" que tiene el elemento
//de la primera peticion"

    let vm = new Object
    const getInfo = () => {
      listeninDb = db.collection('Ruta').onSnapshot( //primera peticion
        res => {
          vm.mainListItems = []
          res.forEach(doc => {
            let newItem = doc.data();
            newItem.id = doc.id;
            if(newItem.cobrador) {
              listeninDb2 = newItem.cobrador.onSnapshot(//segunda peticion
                async res => {
                  newItem.cobradorData = res.data()
                  if(!vm.mainListItems.includes(newItem)){
                    vm.mainListItems.push(newItem)
                  }
                  await setRutasList(vm.mainListItems) //se manda la info al estado
                  console.log(vm.mainListItems)
                }
                )
              } else {
                vm.mainListItems.push(newItem)
              }
            })
          }
        
          )
        }

//useEffect manda a la traer a los datos con la funcion getinfo
//listeninDb y listeninDb2 son funciones que hacer que al destruir el componente se deje de pedir la 
//informacion en tiempo real 

    useEffect(async() => { 
      await getInfo()
      return () => {
        listeninDb();
        listeninDb2();
      }
    }, []);

   }
//Por ultimo retorna la informacion pasandosela a un componente que lo muestra en un rectangulo con 
//estilos de css

return (
  <div className="Rutas">
  <div className="Rutas-options">
    <AddEditButton name="/Rutas/AddRuta" text="Agregar ruta"/>
  </div>
  <div className="Rutas-content">
    {loading && rutasList.map((item) => (
      <RutaCard 
        key={ item.id }
        name={ item.name }
        number={ item.number }
        cobradorName={ `${item.cobradorData.name} ${item.cobradorData.lastName}` }
        id={ item.id }
      />
    ))}
  </div>
</div>
);
```

La informacion la trae de forma correcta, el problema esta en el estado y cuando renderiza su contenido, al ejecutarse por primera me muestra en pantalla solo parte de la informacion, en especifico solo el primer elemento, pero si reviso el estado toda la informacion se encuentra ahi, pero no la renderiza.

Intente poniendole async await a las peticiones pero no me funciona. Lo raro es que esto ocurre solamente cuando hago las dos peticiones de forma anidadas como esta en el codigo anterior, pero si solo hago una peticion funciona de forma correcta.

Me parece que tiene que ver con algo de asincronismo pero no logro encontrar donde esta el problema. pues si vuelvo a llamar a getInfo() unos segundos despues de que la pagina carga muestra toda la informacion del estado pero quiero que lo cargue todo cuando se monte el componente.

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Como recomendación, y según la documentación, el hook useEffect no puede ser asíncrono, si deseas obtener datos de esa manera debes crear una función dentro de useEffect, y ésta debe encargarse de ser asíncrona. [Acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret) te dejo un ejemplo para que lo revises

Comment: Ya cambie lo que comentabas del useEffect pero sigue funcionando igual. Ya esta editado en el codigo de esta publicación

Comment: @AldrichAbdielCorteroGonzale, puedes regresar el código a como lo tenías en un principio? saludos

Comment: Ya lo puse como estaba antes @g.4

Comment: @AldrichAbdielCorteroGonzale Logré emular la secuencia de `getInfo`, eliminé los `async/await` del hook `useEffect`, así como el `async/await`  que esta en la segunda petición, también elimine el `return` que tienes el el hook, es decir el hook `useEffect` solo tiene la llamada a `getInfo` y no tiene dependencias, por favor aplica estos cambios y nos dices que resultado tienes, si puedes incluir los mensajes de la consola o de la terminal en React, debes ver un mensaje como este **React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: `getInfo`**, tal vez @Paulo también noto algo por ahí.